# Is visibility guaranteed for sequential thread runs for non volatile var?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, volatile

I have read below references:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/volatile-keyword-in-java/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

But, I am still not clear on what is the expected behavior in below case:

1. I have a thread pool in which thread is reused.
2. I have a non-volatile var which is accessed by different threads form that thread pool.
3. Threads are run in sequential.(Yes, they can be run in one thread. But, just for this case. So, don't ask why not use one thread)

And the part I am not clear is that. Do I still need volatile to make sure the change made in previous thread is visible to the next thread execution.

Like does java flash thread local cache to memory after each execution?

And does the thread reload the local cache before each execution?

It keep complain there is code section that is not quoted. So, I have to do this. Please help fix.

Comment: *"Please help fix"* Fix what? I don't see any code, so how can we help fix it? Besides, aren't you just asking if field should be volatile or not? What does that *question* have to do with "fixing" anything?

Comment: How do you know the "threads" are run in sequential? --- You seem to be using the word "thread" too much. I believe you means to say that ***tasks*** are run sequentially, potential by different threads from a thread pool.

Comment: @Andreas "Please help fix" is not part of the question. I was blocked from submitting because this website compliant that I have code in my question but not quoted. But, In fact I do not have any code in my question. So, I quote my whole question as code so I can submit. And asked someone to edit.

Comment: @ayrton Thanks for the fix.

Comment: @Andreas I mean thread not task. And the you can get the future before you run the next thread. So that make sure the thread run in sequential. But, as I said, that is not the point of my question.

Comment: It is very much the point of an answer. You said you're using a thread pool, which means that the threads are not really under your control, and that the thread may have been running for a while, before you assign a new task for a thread from the pool to process. Now you say you meant thread, not task, and that you run the next thread, which means you're not using a thread pool. Since anything that happened before you start a thread *happens-before* any code run by the new thread, then you good without `volatile`, but only if a new thread is started, which doesn't happen with pools, so ....

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I do not directly start or end the thread. That is why I said there is a thread pool and threads are re-used. I am not sure how do you define tasks. But, I think you got the question correctly. Let's say threadA run taskA. And we are sure taskA is finished. Then threadB run taskB. Does non-volatile field have visibility and happens-before guaranteed?

Comment: Again, it entirely depends on how you know that `taskA` is finished before `taskB` run. As for "task", I'm using the terminology of [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), and its **documentation**, i.e. the javadoc, says: *"Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` or `Callable` **task** to an `ExecutorService` happen-before any actions taken by that task, ..."* So as you can see, if you *submit* the task after A ends, you might be good, but it all depends ...

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Andreas As Neerav pointed out below. The doc may refer to one single Thread. (Not sure if that is the correct understanding of the statement). But, I would agree the statement is not so clear on that.

Answer (score 1):

Java Memory Model design can answer your question:
In the Java Memory Model a volatile field has a store barrier inserted after a write to it and a load barrier inserted before a read of it.  Qualified final fields of a class have a store barrier inserted after their initialisation to ensure these fields are visible once the constructor completes when a reference to the object is available.

see https://dzone.com/articles/memory-barriersfences

In other words: when a thread tries to read from volatile var JMM forces all CPUs owning this memory area to write back to memory from the local CPU's cache. Then CPU loads its value to the local cache if necessary.

> And the part I am not clear is that. Do I still need volatile to make sure the change made in previous thread is visible to the next thread execution.

Yes and no. Volatile keyword is just for making a value of variable visible to other threads. But if you need only one thread read-write at the moment = you need synchronization. If you need to provide just visibility = volatile keyword is enough.

If you do not use the volatile keyword and share the value through the threads it might be not up to date or even be corrupted. For LONG type Java do 2 writes by 32bits and they are not atomic. Let's say another thread can read the value between these two writes happened.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first. But, I think this doesn't answer my question. What I am concerned is if I don't use volatile. Will the writes in one thread visible to other threads that are running sequentially after it? (Threads are re-used, thus not closed)

Comment: I think volatile have a stronger guarantee that I would needed. (For concurrent threads execution all writes are visible to all threads). But, what I really want to know is does non-volatile field has a less strong guarantee, that sequential threads will see all change made by threads executed before. Or it doesn't.

Comment: @user1947415 post some code with expected behavior or smth to understand what you need

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter whether the Threads are running sequentially for parallely, if you don't use volatile keyword there is no visibility guarantee. That means there is no guarantee that the other thread will see the latest copy as the thread may read the values from register.

Comment: This is the answer I want. But, do you have any reference to support this?

Comment: For example, java could design the Thread this way: when the thread finished each task. It will automatically flash all change from local cache to memory. And whenever a thread start a new task it will reload thread cache from memory. Then even if thread is reading from it's own cache/register. visibility is still guaranteed. But, I am not clear on how Java designed this. And most of the documents only described multiple thread in concurrent case. The case where there is multiple threads but tasks are run in sequentially is not explicitly defined in any doc.

Comment: I think we will have to understand how caching works for this. You can through mechanical sympathy blogs to understand better https://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.com/2011/07/write-combining.html?m=1. The point is if the threads are running on different core than the changes are made to buffers (store/load) which delays the write to cache which will result in other threads not seeing the changes. And that should be true for sequential execution also (if both threads are running in different core)

Comment: you are right about the possible inconsistency between threads running on two cores. But, that doesn't mean java doesn't handle it without volatile in all cases.

Comment: This just explain why there could be a problem of inconsistency when threads running on two cores. But, that doesn't mean java didn't solve it. In fact, volatile is one of the way java provided to fix this. But, that doesn't mean that is the only way. As @Andreas pointed out it seems like ExecutorService will have happen-before guarantee for sequential thread runs. And, I assume that covers the case where threads are running on different cores. Then it seems like in this case, even without volatile visibility is still guaranteed.

Comment: It's not about sequential thread run. It is about where you start the thread from. If thread A is doing some work and thread A itself submits a task B then everything in A will be visible to B. That is what executor service doc says about.

Comment: Hmm... The statement seems confusing. I am not sure if you can translate the doc that way. But, neither can I be sure it's translated the other way I thought. Still no answer here.

Comment: There are up to 3 threads involved here: 1) The thread running task A. 2) The thread submitting task B. 3) The thread running task B. As the javadoc of `ExecutorService` says: *"Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` or `Callable` task to an `ExecutorService` happen-before any actions taken by that task, ..."* So, if you can establish a *happen-before* between the end of task A and the submit of task B, then there is a *happen-before* between end of A and start of B, which means you don't need `volatile`, even if thread 3 comes from a pool.

Comment: @andreas in this case for A happens Before B.. Thread running task A should be the one who submits the task B

Comment: @NeeravVadodaria OP hasn't explained how the code that submits task B knows that task A has completed. It could be last step in task A, which ensures that actions of task A *happens-before* submit of task B. Or it could be some other logic, which then requires that you ensure a *happens-before* boundary, as I said. Since OP hasn't said enough to know, I left comment open to be either way.

Comment: @Andreas agreed. OP is not clear how the task are submitted